# Do stats from your last company carry over?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

When you end the game do any of your stats carry over? Such as, stuff you have researched and what not?

Answer (score 4):

You have the option to carry over all the information (called "hints") that creating a "game report" gave you, but not things you actually researched.